# kSoap2 send collection

Tags: java, .net, android, android-ksoap2

i have android application, which send some data to .net web service (not wcf, simple web service)
on android application i have class, which implement KvmSerializable interface

```
public class OrderDTO extends BaseSoapObject
{
    public int ID;
    public Date OrderDate;
    public UserDTO Owner; 
    public Vector<OrderItemDTO> Products;

    @Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info)
{
    switch(index)
    {
        case 0:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "ID";
            break;

        case 1:
            info.type = MarshalDate.DATE_CLASS;
            info.name = "OrderDate";
            break;

        case 2:
            info.type = UserDTO.class;
            info.name = "Owner";
            break;

        case 3:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.VECTOR_CLASS;
            info.name = "Products";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }       
}
}
```

on the server side i have class

```
public class OrderDTO
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserDTO Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderItemDTO[] Products { get; set; }

    public OrderDTO()
    {    
    }
}
```

and the web service method

[WebMethod]

```
public void SaveOrder(OrderDTO order)
{
    try
    {
        // do somthing
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
    }
```

}

i have succeed call this method from android, field Owner and OrderDate are correctly filled, but the Products field is empty (not null, just empty)

i try to use Array, ArrayList and Vector - no changes

when i see request dump and see that the only different there is (tag name of the item of collection:

```
<Products i:type="c:Array" c:arrayType="d:anyType[1]">
    <item i:type="n0:OrderItemDTO">
       <ID i:type="d:int">0</ID>
       <AssignedCode i:type="d:string">0001</AssignedCode>
       <Count i:type="d:int">5</Count>
    </item>
</Products>
```

and in my wsdl:

```
<Products>
    <OrderItemDTO>
        <ID>int</ID>
        <Count>int</Count>
        <AssignedCode>string</AssignedCode>
    </OrderItemDTO>
    <OrderItemDTO>
        <ID>int</ID>
        <Count>int</Count>
        <AssignedCode>string</AssignedCode>
    </OrderItemDTO>
</Products>
```

and my android code for interaction with service:

```
OrderDTO dto = new OrderDTO(order);
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Namespace, SaveOrderMethod);

PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("order");
pi.setValue(dto);
pi.setType(dto.getClass());
request.addProperty(pi); 

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

envelope.addMapping(Namespace, "OrderItemDTO", new OrderItemDTO().getClass());
envelope.addMapping(Namespace, "UserDTO", new UserDTO().getClass());
envelope.addMapping(Namespace, "OrderDTO", new OrderDTO().getClass());

Marshal dateMarshal = new MarshalDate();
dateMarshal.register(envelope);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Url);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

try
{
    androidHttpTransport.call(SaveOrderSoapAction, envelope);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    Log.e(Tag, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: i have found the answer

i need to add some code to OrderDTO.getPropertyInfo method

    PropertyInfo elementInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    elementInfo.name = "OrderItemDTO";
    elementInfo.type = new OrderItemDTO().getClass();    
    info.elementType = elementInfo;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the answer i need to add some code to OrderDTO.getPropertyInfo method PropertyInfo elementInfo = new PropertyInfo(); elementInfo.name = "OrderItemDTO"; elementInfo.type = new OrderItemDTO().getClass(); info.elementType = elementInfo;